# Dynamic cast behavior in loop

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, polymorphism

I'm trying to accomplish some hacking & slashing and was wondering how to approach the following.

There are 2 interfaces defined:

```
public interface IBase
{
    string Name { get; }
    void Run();
}

public interface ISecondBase<T> : IEntityTask
{
    Thing<T> Thing { get; }
}
```

Somewhere else I have a list of IBase.

This list is filled ISecondBase. I would like to be able to loop through the list of Base, but using some reflection tricks and hacks als be able to call Thing on the items. I know they're there, the compiler doesn't.

So I'd have to cast it to its concrete type at runtime, but this cast has to be dynamic, based on reflected information in the loop... So all type information is dynamic... I'm starting to think in circles :)

Since I know on beforehand that everything inside it is always of the SecondBase type, I decided to use the dynamic keyword and just let it resolve at runtime. This seems to me like an easy way out. Is there some best practice for these cases? Should I redesign, without loss of generality, and how?

```
foreach(var x in y)
{
    dynamic melp = x;
    melp.Thingy;
}
```

Where to start?

Edit: Perhaps some more code to make the example less contrived.

I have the base classes as mentioned. In real life they look like this:

```
public interface IEntityTask
{
    string Name { get; }

    void Run();
}

public interface IEntityTask<T> : IEntityTask
{
    Task<T> Task { get; }
}

//Then there are classes that implement these:

public class CreateEntityTask<T> : IEntityTask<Guid> 
{
    public T Entity { get; private set; }
    public Func<T, Guid> EntityMethod { get; private set; }
    public Task<Guid> Task { get; private set; }

    public void Run()
    {
       Task = Task<Guid>.Run(() => entityAccess.CreateEntity<T>(Entity, EntityMethod));                

    }
}

public class ReadEntityTask<T> : IEntityTask<T> 
{
    public Guid EntityId { get; private set; }
    public Func<Guid, T> EntityMethod { get; private set; }
    public Task<T> Task { get; private set; }

    public void Run()
    {
       Task = Task<T>.Run(() => entityAccess.ReadEntity<T>(EntityId, EntityMethod));                

    }
}

//Furthermore there is a class called EntityTaskManager, which holds a list of these things and runs, awaits & collects the results on them.

public class EntityTaskManager
{
    public List<IEntityTask> EntityTasks { get; set; } //  I want tasks of Guid and bool in here!!!!
    public Dictionary<string, object> EntityTaskResults { get; set; }       
}
```

In a calling class I construct a new EntityTask and add it to the list. And then call RunTasks on the manager.

Comment: There are a few uses of `dynamic`; this is not one of them, IMO. Why can't an `interface` be used?

Comment: so, if `base is ISecondBase<>`, your get a `dynamic thing`, what are you going to do with it? Thats the interface you need as a contstraint on `T` of `ISecondBase<T>`.

Comment: Your question looks too far-fetched... It's not clear, how do you create items in the list, what do you plan to do with `Thing`... Can you change interface definitions? Maybe, you'll tell about your *real* task?

Comment: ISecondBase<T> in real life holds a Task<T>. A list of these is constructed. All of them have to be waited for. After that the results of them will be fetched.

Comment: @Apeiron: that is, `Thing<T>` equals `Task<T>`? OK, imagine, that you've fetched results. Since they could be of very different types, how do you want to store them? Will `IEnumerable<object>` be enough? Also, you've ignored the question about types design: can you change these interfaces and their implementations?

Comment: @Dennis, I've added some more information. The results are known to be of certain types. And yes, IEnumerable<object> is enough, I'm using a dictionary for it now.

Comment: If the T types are known in advance you might do something like var guidTask = EntityTask as IEntityTask<Guid>; If(guidTask != null)... But this is looking like a severe case of Over Engineering.

Comment: Over-engineering is kind of the point of this project ;) I need to write more code to actually get better :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd modify `IEntityTask` like this:

```
public interface IEntityTask
{
    string Name { get; }
    void Run();
    object Result { get; }
}
```

If `EntityTaskManager` is the only place, where you work with `IEntityTask` type, the implementation of `Result` would be explicit:

```
public class CreateEntityTask<T> : IEntityTask<Guid> 
{
    /* The rest of code here */
    object IEntityTask.Result
    {
        get { return Task.Result; }
    }
}
```

Then fetching task results should be trivial:

```
var results = entityTasksManager
    .EntityTasks
    .Select(t => t.Result);
```

Comment: Tomorrow I've some time to work on this again, I'll get back to you about this. Thanks in advance!